# Is Zend's "from()" function sql injection safe?

Tags: zend-framework, sql-injection, zend-db

I was going to fetch a column from database given as a POST param, so I started to write a code:

```
$db->select()->from('table', array('field' => $PARAM))->query()->fetchAll();
```

Then I started to wonder if it is safe method to pass `$PARAM` to the query? I searched some web and documentation but didn't find unequivocal answer.
So I made some experimets, giving the `$PARAM` different values and watching output query. What I noticed was that ` characters were prepended by another ` characters, but \ or \n etc. remained unchanged.
My question is: Is it safe? Is it enough to escape only ` characters? [Manual](http://php.net//manual/pl/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) says, that those other characters should also be escaped.

Comment: It uses [prepared statements with PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/149998) rather than the deprecated `mysql_` functions. So yes, it's safe.

Comment: Have you already looked at the [source code](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1)?